# when i give datasource to gridview, the combo in grid is auto selecting

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

after giving the datasource to grid the first cell of gridview combo is auto selection occuring in datagridview, how to prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a dropdown list you have to populate it separately and insert "Select" as 0th item.
I assume this is asp.net application. Here is the link how you can populate and bind dropdown in gridview. 
[how to bind a dropdownlist in gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329224/how-to-bind-a-dropdownlist-in-gridview)

Comment: It looks to me like the combo is already populated, and usually your datasource has a value for that column and you WANT it to be selected (but not dropped down that's weird)